# Automapper: Set parent object to null if all child attributes are null

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, automapper

Currently the way my automapper setup works is on the domain > outbound response DTO mapping, I will filter out attributes that are either invalid or are null using the ForMember methods.

Problem:

Dto Model:

```
Id
Name
EntityDataDto
     Type?
     Amount?
```

EntityDataDto is an object on the main Dto Model, but if type & amount (both nullable) are null, EntityDataDto will not automatically be set to null, it will be of type EntityData with both fields as null, which I would like to omit from the response. In the response body, EntityData will be an empty property, when I don't want it shown at all. JsonConvert will handle serializing away the type and amount properties, but not the parent object.

The way I have currently solved this is on the DtoModel mapping profile, creating a ForMember condition where Automapper will only resolve the value of EntityDataDto if either type & amount are not null.

Is there a way that I can automatically set the parent object to null so that the serializer will pick up the null object and filter it out using JsonConvert? It doesn't seem maintainable in the long run to have the mapping profile do this. I would also not like to maintain resolvers which will handle this logic.

Comment: If your concern is your serialization, wouldn't the concern be best placed there? either way you will likely want a converter for either automapper or josn serializer

Comment: How does the serializer pick up on an empty object? I only know of NullValueHandling setting in JsonConvert

Comment: Which in my experience will only handle the serialization of null fields, not objects

Comment: Both automapper and json.net and most other serializer have converters to handle the more complex cases

Comment: This doesn't sound like such a complex case though, if all of the attributes in an object are null, there is no way to automatically set that object to null? I would like to avoid having to maintain individual converters, or is there a way I can create a generic converter which checks all properties